# Problems with downloading copies of signed documents on my server through the docusign rest api

Tags: asp.net, rest, pdf, docusignapi

I am using docusign rest api in my asp.net mvc application. I uploaded a .docx file to docusign. After signing, i am downloading this file . It gets downloaded as .docx file itself. But not able to open it. When I open the same file with adobe reader, it can be opened as pdf file. Can anyone help me to download the signed document as pdf so that i can open it easily?

```
        static string email = "****";   // your account email
        static string password = "****";    // your account password
        static string integratorKey = "******"; 
        static string recipientName = "***";    
        static string documentName = "test1.docx";  
        static string baseURL = ""; 
 public void UploadtoDocuSign(int DocId, string DocName, int ObjectTypeId, int ObjectId)
        {
            try
            {
                User _dealuser = _imanageVacancy.GetDealById(ObjectId).LeadUser;
                string recipientName = _dealuser.FirstName + " " + _dealuser.LastName;  // provide a recipient (signer's) name
                string documentName = DocName;
                string recipientEmail = _dealuser.EmailAddress;
                string sectionname = "";
                DocumentManager _docmanager = GetDocumentById(DocId);
                if (_docmanager.SectionID != null)
                    sectionname = "\\" + GetSectionName_additionalDoc((int)_docmanager.SectionID);
                string FileNameWithPath = CommonFunctions.ConfigReader.GetConfigValue("appSettings", "FileUploadPath") + "\\Documents\\" + EnumsNeeded.VacancySubMenu.Deal.ToString() + "\\" + ObjectId + sectionname + "\\" + documentName;
                //============================================================================
                // STEP 1 - Login API Call (used to retrieve your baseUrl)
                //============================================================================
                // Endpoint for Login api call (in demo environment):
                string url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
                // set request url, method, and headers. No body needed for login api call
                HttpWebRequest request = initializeRequest(url, "GET", null, email, password);
                // read the http response
                string response = getResponseBody(request);
                // parse baseUrl from response body
                baseURL = parseDataFromResponse(response, "baseUrl");
                //============================================================================
                // STEP 2 - Send Signature Request from Template
                //============================================================================

                /*
                This is the only DocuSign API call that requires a "multipart/form-data" content type. We will be
                constructing a request body in the following format (each newline is a CRLF):

                --AAA
                Content-Type: application/xml
                Content-Disposition: form-data

                <XML BODY GOES HERE>
                --AAA
                Content-Type:application/pdf
                Content-Disposition: file; filename="document.pdf"; documentid=1

                <DOCUMENT BYTES GO HERE>
                --AAA--
                */

                // append "/envelopes" to baseURL and use for signature request api call
                url = baseURL + "/envelopes";
                // construct an outgoing XML formatted request body (JSON also accepted)
                // .. following body adds one signer and places a signature tab 100 pixels to the right
                // and 100 pixels down from the top left corner of the document you supply
                string xmlBody =
                "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
                "<emailSubject>DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document</emailSubject>" +
                "<status>sent</status>" + // "sent" to send immediately, "created" to save as draft in your account
                    // add document(s)
                "<documents>" +
                "<document>" +
                "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
                "<name>" + documentName + "</name>" +
                "</document>" +
                "</documents>" +
                    // add recipient(s)
                "<recipients>" +
                "<signers>" +
                "<signer>" +
                "<recipientId>1</recipientId>" +
                "<email>" + recipientEmail + "</email>" +
                "<name>" + recipientName + "</name>" +
                "<tabs>" +
                "<signHereTabs>" +
                "<signHere>" +
                "<xPosition>100</xPosition>" + // default unit is pixels
                "<yPosition>100</yPosition>" + // default unit is pixels
                "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
                "<pageNumber>4</pageNumber>" +
                "</signHere>" +
                "</signHereTabs>" +
                "</tabs>" +
                "</signer>" +
                "</signers>" +
                "</recipients>" +
                "</envelopeDefinition>";
                // set request url, method, headers. Don't set the body yet, we'll set that separelty after
                // we read the document bytes and configure the rest of the multipart/form-data request
                request = initializeRequest(url, "POST", null, email, password);

                // some extra config for this api call
                configureMultiPartFormDataRequest(request, xmlBody, documentName, FileNameWithPath);

                // read the http response
                response = getResponseBody(request);

                string envelopeId = parseDataFromResponse(response, "envelopeId");
                _docmanager.DocuSignReferenceId = envelopeId;
                _docmanager.DocuSignStatus = "Sent";
                _iDocRep.Update(_docmanager);
                _unitOfWork.Commit();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                using (WebResponse response = ex.Response)
                {
                    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                    Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
                    using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        string text = new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void DocuSignDownload()
        {
            try
            {
                //============================================================================
                // STEP 1 - Login API Call (used to retrieve your baseUrl)
                //============================================================================
                // Endpoint for Login api call (in demo environment):
                string url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
                // set request url, method, and headers. No body needed for login api call
                HttpWebRequest request = initializeRequest(url, "GET", null, email, password);
                // read the http response
                string response = getResponseBody(request);
                // parse baseUrl from response body
                baseURL = parseDataFromResponse(response, "baseUrl");
                //============================================================================
                // STEP 2 - Get Statuses of a set of envelopes
                //============================================================================
                //*** This example gets statuses of all envelopes in your account going back 1 month...

                int curr_month = System.DateTime.Now.Month;
                int curr_day = System.DateTime.Now.Day;
                int curr_year = System.DateTime.Now.Year;
                if (curr_month != 1)
                {
                    curr_month -= 1;
                }
                else
                { // special case for january
                    curr_month = 12;
                    curr_year -= 1;
                }

                // append "/envelopes?from_date=MONTH/DAY/YEAR" and use in get statuses api call
                // we need to URL encode the slash (/) chars, whos URL encoding is: %2F
                url = baseURL + "/envelopes?from_date=" + curr_month.ToString() + "%2F" + curr_day.ToString() + "%2F" + curr_year.ToString();
                // set request url, method, and headers. No request body for this api call...
                request = initializeRequest(url, "GET", null, email, password);
                // read the http response
                response = getResponseBody(request);
                string ComplenvIds = CompletedenvelopeIds(response);
                ComplenvIds = ComplenvIds.TrimEnd(',');
                string[] envIds = ComplenvIds.Split(',');

                foreach (var envid in envIds)
                {
                    DocumentManager _doc = _iDocRep.Get(x => x.DocuSignReferenceId == envid);
                    if (_doc != null)
                    {
                        DownloadCompletedEnvelopes(envid, _doc);
                        _doc.DocuSignStatus = "Completed";
                        _iDocRep.Update(_doc);
                        _unitOfWork.Commit();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                using (WebResponse response = ex.Response)
                {
                    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                    Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
                    using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        string text = new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void DownloadCompletedEnvelopes(string envId, DocumentManager doc)
        {
            try
            {
                //============================================================================
                // STEP 1 - Login API Call (used to retrieve your baseUrl)
                //============================================================================
                // Endpoint for Login api call (in demo environment):
                string url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
                // set request url, method, and headers. No body needed for login api call
                HttpWebRequest request = initializeRequest(url, "GET", null, email, password);
                // read the http response
                string response = getResponseBody(request);
                // parse baseUrl from response body
                baseURL = parseDataFromResponse(response, "baseUrl");
                //============================================================================
                // STEP 2 - Get Envelope Document(s) List and Info
                //============================================================================
                // append "/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents" to to baseUrl and use for next endpoint
                url = baseURL + "/envelopes/" + envId + "/documents";
                //url = baseURL + "/envelopes/";
                // set request url, method, body, and headers
                request = initializeRequest(url, "GET", null, email, password);
                // read the http response
                response = getResponseBody(request);

                // store each document name and uri locally, so that we can subsequently download each one
                Dictionary<string, string> docsList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                string uri, name;
                using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(response)))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "envelopeDocument"))
                        {
                            XmlReader reader2 = reader.ReadSubtree();
                            uri = ""; name = "";
                            while (reader2.Read())
                            {
                                if ((reader2.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader2.Name == "name"))
                                {
                                    name = reader2.ReadString();
                                }
                                if ((reader2.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader2.Name == "uri"))
                                {
                                    uri = reader2.ReadString();
                                }
                            }// end while
                            docsList.Add(name, uri);
                        }
                    }
                }

                //============================================================================
                // STEP 3 - Download the Document(s)
                //============================================================================

                //string envelopeID = "Some EnvelopeID";
                //EnvelopePDF envPDF = apiService.RequestPDF(envelopeID);
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in docsList)
                {
                    // append document uri to baseUrl and use to download each document(s)
                    url = baseURL + kvp.Value;
                    // set request url, method, body, and headers
                    request = initializeRequest(url, "GET", null, email, password);
                    request.Accept = "application/pdf"; // documents are converted to PDF in the DocuSign cloud
                    // read the response and store into a local file:
                    HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                    string sectionname = "";
                    if (doc.SectionID != null)
                        sectionname = "\\" + GetSectionName_additionalDoc((int)doc.SectionID);
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    using (FileStream outfile = new FileStream(CommonFunctions.ConfigReader.GetConfigValue("appSettings", "FileUploadPath") + "\\Documents\\" + EnumsNeeded.VacancySubMenu.Deal.ToString() + "\\" + doc.ObjectID + sectionname + "\\" + kvp.Key, FileMode.Create))
                    {  

                            webResponse.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(ms);
                            if (ms.Length > int.MaxValue)
                            {
                                throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot write a file larger than 2GB.");
                            }
                            outfile.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\nDone downloading document(s), check local directory.");
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                using (WebResponse response = ex.Response)
                {
                    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                    Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
                    using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        string text = new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //***********************************************************************************************
        // --- HELPER FUNCTIONS ---
        //***********************************************************************************************
        public static HttpWebRequest initializeRequest(string url, string method, string body, string email, string password)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = method;
            addRequestHeaders(request, email, password);
            if (body != null)
                addRequestBody(request, body);
            return request;
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public static void addRequestHeaders(HttpWebRequest request, string email, string password)
        {
            // authentication header can be in JSON or XML format. XML used for this walkthrough:
            string authenticateStr =
            "<DocuSignCredentials>" +
            "<Username>" + email + "</Username>" +
            "<Password>" + password + "</Password>" +
            "<IntegratorKey>" + integratorKey + "</IntegratorKey>" + // global (not passed)
            "</DocuSignCredentials>";
            request.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authenticateStr);
            request.Accept = "application/xml";
            request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        }

        public static void addRequestBody(HttpWebRequest request, string requestBody)
        {
            // create byte array out of request body and add to the request object
            byte[] body = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody);
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(body, 0, requestBody.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
        }

        public static void configureMultiPartFormDataRequest(HttpWebRequest request, string xmlBody, string docName, string FileNameWithPath)
        {
            // overwrite the default content-type header and set a boundary marker
            request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=BOUNDARY";
            // start building the multipart request body
            string requestBodyStart = "\r\n\r\n--BOUNDARY\r\n" +
            "Content-Type: application/xml\r\n" +
            "Content-Disposition: form-data\r\n" +
            "\r\n" +
            xmlBody + "\r\n\r\n--BOUNDARY\r\n" + // our xml formatted envelopeDefinition
            "Content-Type: application/pdf\r\n" +
            "Content-Disposition: file; filename=\"" + docName + "\"; documentId=1\r\n" +
            "\r\n";
            string requestBodyEnd = "\r\n--BOUNDARY--\r\n\r\n";
            // read contents of provided document into the request stream
            FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(FileNameWithPath);
            // write the body of the request
            byte[] bodyStart = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBodyStart.ToString());
            byte[] bodyEnd = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBodyEnd.ToString());
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(bodyStart, 0, requestBodyStart.ToString().Length);
            // Read the file contents and write them to the request stream. We read in blocks of 4096 bytes
            byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
            int len;
            while ((len = fileStream.Read(buf, 0, 4096)) > 0)
            {
                dataStream.Write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            dataStream.Write(bodyEnd, 0, requestBodyEnd.ToString().Length);
            dataStream.Close();
        }

        public static string getResponseBody(HttpWebRequest request)
        {
            // read the response stream into a local string
            HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
            string responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
            return responseText;
        }

        public static string parseDataFromResponse(string response, string searchToken)
        {
            // look for "searchToken" in the response body and parse its value
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(response)))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == searchToken))
                        return reader.ReadString();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static string CompletedenvelopeIds(string response)
        {
            string compenvIds = "";
            string envId = "";
            // look for "searchToken" in the response body and parse its value
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(response)))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "envelopes"))
                    {
                        XmlReader reader2 = reader.ReadSubtree();
                        while (reader2.Read())
                        {
                            if ((reader2.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader2.Name == "envelope"))
                            {
                                XmlReader reader3 = reader2.ReadSubtree();
                                envId = "";
                                while (reader3.Read())
                                {
                                    if ((reader3.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader3.Name == "envelopeId"))
                                    {
                                        envId = reader3.ReadString();
                                    }
                                    if ((reader3.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader3.Name == "status"))
                                    {
                                        if (reader3.ReadString() == "completed")
                                            compenvIds = string.Concat(compenvIds, envId + ",");
                                    }

                                    if ((reader3.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader3.Name == "status"))
                                    {
                                        DateTime date = reader3.ReadContentAsDateTime();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return compenvIds;
        }

        public List<Lookup> LookupCache()
        {
            List<Lookup> _lookup = (List<Lookup>)HttpContext.Current.Cache["Lookup"];
            if (HttpContext.Current.Cache["Lookup"] == null)
                _lookup = _imanageUser.UpdateCache();
            return _lookup;
        }

        string GetSectionName_additionalDoc(int SectionId)
        {
            List<Lookup> _lookup = LookupCache();
            string _section = _lookup.Find(x => x.LookupType == (int)EnumsNeeded.EnumTypes.AdditionalDocumentTypes && x.LookupId == SectionId).LookupDesc;
            return _section;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All files that come from DocuSign are going to be .PDF files. 
Your documents will be saved as the name they were uploaded as (often contain the extension). So if you're writing the file with the name that it is stored in DocuSign by `DocumentPDF->Name`. I would do a .Replace and replace the extension with .pdf.

Comment: You mean 'after downloading the file, replace the extension with .pdf'? Can i rename the file before storing?

Comment: yeah, it's already going to be in PDF format, just make sure the extension saves as .pdf and you should be fine.

Comment: using (FileStream outfile = new FileStream("[path]\\" + kvp.Key, FileMode.Create)) In this kvp.key is test1.docx. I changed that to using (FileStream outfile = new FileStream("[path]\\" + "test1.pdf", FileMode.Create)) but it corrupts the file and i couldnt open it

Comment: Can you post that file somewhere?

Comment: Its now working fine. I don't know what went wrong earlier. Same code when extension replaced with pdf is working fine now. Thank You :)